# MATLAB GUIDE - How to display results on a single editbox after pressing the pushbutton

Tags: matlab-guide, editbox

I am trying to create a matlab gui using GUIDE, and have been looking for a solution to the following problem.

I have the following:

1. An editbox that will take user input
2. A listbox with choices to choose, and once a type is chosen, data is analyzed.
3. Another editbox, which serves as a result-box to display the user-input #1 and analyzed   data #2, after a run-button is pushed.
4. A run-button (pushbutton)

Problem:

When I put only the user-input(#1) and push the run-button, the user-input is displayed in the result-box properly. However, when I put both the user-input and analyzed the data, and push the run-button, only the result from the analyzed data (#2) is displayed in the result-box.

Question:

How can I display both #1 and #2 in the same result-box(editbox) after I push the run-button?

FYI:

I have changed the max - min > 1 in the editbox property, and can scroll up and down.

Thanks for the help peeps!

Comment: Could you please post the button Callback function? Also a screenshot of the GUI could be helpful...

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.Thanks though